# Elegant way to init and extend a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a sweet way to init an array if not already initilized?
Currently the code looks something like:

```
if (!obj) var obj = [];
obj.push({});
```

cool would be something like `var obj = (obj || []).push({})`, but that does not work :-(

Comment: Um... Thats an odd position for `var obj`.. after `if(!obj)`, doesn't make a lot of sense, is `obj` also defined in a higher scope or something?

Comment: javascript does not init an extra scope inside if/else

Comment: I know this, which is why I'm wondering why you would ever conditionally define a `var` like that... I'm assuming `obj` is probably a function parameter, and the keyword `var` in there is just useless / unwanted...  If not, there is no way `obj` could ever be defined before this call... Try `obj={}; (function() { if (!obj) var obj = []; console.log(obj); })();` -- You'll get `[]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create array and push into it in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614134/create-array-and-push-into-it-in-one-line)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`var obj = (obj || []).push({})` doesn't work because `push` returns the new length of the array. For a new object, it will create `obj` with value of 1. For an existing object it might raise an error - if `obj` is a number, it does not have a `push` function.

You should do OK with:

```
var obj = obj || [];
obj.push({});
```

Comment: The sillier one-liner `(obj = obj||[]) && obj.push({}) && obj` might do what he is looking for...

Comment: @gnarf - Interesting idea. If I understand correctly, the line should still start with `var obj = `.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is:

```
var obj; 
(obj = (obj || [])).push({});
```

Comment: except implicitly, `obj` *should* always be undefined in this case, which makes the `(obj || [])` just `[]`

Comment: No it won't. `var obj;` won't set `obj` to `undefined` if it was `defined` before.

Comment: Unless you are using `var obj` twice in the same scope, which just seems like a waste of the `var` to me...

Answer (score 2):

Just a tiny tweak to your idea to make it work

```
var obj = (obj || []).concat([{}]);
```

Comment: Although, `concat` actually returns a completely new array...  Meaning if obj was already defined (which i'm still curious how that might happen), it will not have the `{}` added to it in any parent scope...

Comment: That's true, but there's no scope information in the original question.  Also, since he's using an assignment statement in his attempt, mutation clearly isn't a requirement.

Comment: His original seems to state: `obj` should either stay as it is, or become an empty array, then `push` something onto it... The problem being that `push` wouldn't happen on the original `obj` so if that `obj` was a reference to a different array, or a function parameter, etc... your code would not do the same thing...

Comment: The code in the accepted answer refutes the point you're trying to make.  `obj.push()` executes no matter what the original state of `obj` is

Answer (score 0):

```
with(obj = obj || []) push({});
```

Comment: I think your pre-edit was superior: `(obj || [{}])` is functional.

Comment: -1: erk! never ever *ever* use the "with" feature of Javascript.

Comment: I fear to use the `with` statement as Douglas Crockford told me (http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) that bad unforseen things can happen on its usage

Comment: @annakata unfortunatly the pre-edit would only add `{}` to the array if it didn't already exist, and leave it as is otherwise. I realized this shortly after I posted. @Spudley - please explain why its usage is harmful in this case. @sod - and what bad unforeseen things could possibly happen with this simple line of code? There is no ambiguity at all.

Comment: +1 to counter the with-hate: `with` is a powerful tool whether crockford likes it or not, it's just a matter of understanding the tool *as is everything else*. A good coder knows when to break rules.

Comment: @MooGoo - ah, subtle - I read the OP as wanting exactly that, but you're right it could go either way. Well that's a much more boring question now :)

Comment: Spudley, sod: a better rule would be to read the articles of influential people carefully and then think about it for yourself before making your mind up. Crockford or anyone else saying that `with` is evil evil evil does not make it true.