# Create array and push into it in one line

Tags: javascript

The following is just a theoretical JavaScript question. I am curious if the following can be converting into a single statement:

```
if(!window.foo){
  window.foo = [];
}
window.foo.push('bar');
```

everyone has probably written this code before, but can it be done in one line?
At first I thought something like this would work:

```
(window.foo || window.foo = []).push('bar');
```

but that doesn't work because of an invalid assignment. Next I tried chaining something on the push, but that doesn't work because push does not return the array.

Any thoughts on if this can be done in plain JavaScript?
(the result by the way should be that `window.foo = ['bar']`)

Comment: Why do you need it in one line? most devs do `foo = foo || [];`

Comment: I'm assuming you specifically want to use the `push` function? otherwise you could just have `window.foo = window.foo || ['bar']`

Comment: `(window.foo || (window.foo = [])).push('bar');` also works.

Comment: @Jeff I think he wants to push `bar` onto an existing `foo` too.

Comment: yeah, this is something that would be in a loop, i should have mentioned it

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @jeff - i dont think so, this is a real usecase

Comment: @mkoryak, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74041760/7753089

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You've got your assignment backwards*. It should be:

```
(window.foo = window.foo || []).push('bar');
```

The `||` operator in JavaScript *does not return a boolean value*. If the left hand side is truthy, it returns the left hand side, otherwise it returns the right hand side.

```
a = a || [];
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a ? a : [];
```

So an alternative way of writing the above is:

```
(window.foo = window.foo ? window.foo : []).push('bar');
```

* see comments for details

Comment: No, the assignment isn't backwards, it's just a problem with operator priorities. What you show is a different way of doing it; it always assigns a value to the property instead of only doing the assignment if the property is not set.

Answer (score 17):

Your code works just fine if you add parentheses so that it does what you intended:

```
(window.foo || (window.foo = [])).push('bar');
```

Without the parentheses, it thinks that it should evaluate `window.foo || window.foo` first, and then assign the array to the result of that, which is not possible.

Comment: It is great stuff like this works, but who wants to maintain it! I do not raise my hand.

Comment: @epascarello I'd be fine with it. zzzzBov's answer is nicer, and it would be even nicer to have it on one line, but I can read this without pausing just fine - it's just what you're used to.

Answer (score 17):

### 2021 Update

@zzzzBov's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14614169/290085),

```
(window.foo = window.foo || []).push('bar');
```

can be further simplified using the new `||=` operator, [*logical OR assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)<sup>1</sup>,

```
(window.foo ||= []).push('bar');
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [tcs39/proposal-logical-assignment](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment), currently in [Stage](https://tc39.es/process-document/) 4, and [supported by major browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_logical_or_assignment).

Answer (score 14):

This question got me playing with different options for fun. It's too bad `push` returns the length instead of the original array reference, but for even shorter expressions it can be helpful to have something that can be immediately iterated, mapped, etc.

```
window.foo = (window.foo||[]).concat(['bar']); // always returns array, allowing:
(window.foo = (window.foo||[]).concat(['bar'])).forEach( ... )

(window.foo = window.foo||[]).push('bar'); // always returns length

window.foo && window.foo.push('bar') || (window.foo = ['bar']); // playing around
```

Answer (score 7):

The shortest way to do this is using **Logical Nullish Assignment**:

```js
(window.foo ??= []).push('bar');
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.concat` instead of `.push`, since `.concat` returns the array and `.push` returns the array's length.

```js
window.foo = (window.foo || []).concat('bar');
```

This way the code is easier to read and understand.

---

Shorter version with a new `||=` operator: *(may be slightly harder to read though)*

```js
window.foo ||= [].concat('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case where I needed to merge the contents of two arrays if they existed, I made use of the spread operator:

```
window.foo = [...['bar'], ...window.foo ?== []]
```

This works for any array including 'bar'.