# Is it possible to conditionally add an element to a possibly undefined array on an object in one line in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with ids for keys that I want to conditionally add an array to.  I could do this, but I don't want this code repeated 3 times in my function:

```js
const myObj = {};
const myKey = '1233';
const myValue = true;

if (!(myKey in myObj)) {
    myObj[myKey] = [];
}
myObj[myKey].push(myValue);
```

I would like to do something `myObj.upsert(myKey, myValue)`, but [modifying the Object prototype currently causes performance issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).  Using Object.create (as suggested) causes a lot of TypeScript issues in my application and I was casting my object back to one without the upsert method to pass it along which felt bloated and wrong.

So I opted to use the [nullish coelescing assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) in my code:

```js
const myObj = {};
const myKey = '1234';
const myValue = true;

myObj[myKey] ??= [];
myObj[myKey].push(myValue);
```

and that works great! But, is it possible to do this in one line?

I was thinking something like this might work, but no:

```js
myObj[myKey] ??= [...myObj[myKey], myValue]
```

Comment: `(myObj[myKey] ??= []).push(myValue)` :D . btw why 1 line

Comment: Yes, you can write your whole code in one line. Line breaks are optional in JavaScript

Comment: is "=" after ?? necessary/needed?

Comment: @cmgchess For readability and mostly just wondering.  Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @user1514042, yes, otherwise you populate an array (`[]`) that is ignored. Try for yourself.

Comment: I don't really get it but the code looks confusing.

Comment: `myObj[myKey].upsert(myValue)` would not even work if `myObj[myKey]` is `undefined`. Did you mean `myObj.upsert(myKey, myValue)`?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, good catch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614134/create-array-and-push-into-it-in-one-line

Comment: @cmgchess The other advantage to your method is the code maintenance is reduced.  The number of `myObj`, `myKey`, `myValue` in my code is greatly reduced from the original.

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks, that post is related and summarizes the solution to the problem well, but I was also wondering if this is the best pattern to use here?  See my comment on the answer below.

Comment: i guess its just personal preference. i find the 2 line solution somewhat more readable.

Comment: Fair enough then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nullish-coalescing assignment operator forms an *expression*. You don't have to put it in a separate statement (line):

```
(myObj[myKey] ??= []).push(myValue);
```

Comment: Is this a common pattern for object assignment that people use? I've never seen it before, but I like it. Or is there a better way to conditionally push a value to a array on a dynamically-keyed object (not that I see anything wrong here)?

Comment: @JonathanRys Yes, but it's common in modern code only, as the `??=` operator was introduced quite recently